# I want to enable "Null safety" in flutter project How should I do this?

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I have to enable this feature to add some dependencies. I tried several methods, but I still could not add the dependency I want to add "video_player" and "showcaseview" dependencies My Dart version is 3.0.5 my sdk version : sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

run 'dart pub upgrade --null-safety' i got an error 'The `--null-safety` flag is no longer supported. Consider using the Dart 2.19 sdk to migrate to null safety.'

Comment: What happens if you just run: `flutter pub get` in your project?

Comment: When I run 'flutter pub get' it gives me an error: Package not available (authorization failed)

Comment: Try with `flutter upgrade` first

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

To enable null safety and add the "video_player" and "showcaseview" dependencies to your Flutter project:

1. Update your Dart SDK version in your `pubspec.yaml` file to at least 2.12.0:

   ```yaml
   environment:
     sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
   ```
2. Make sure you have Flutter version 2.0.0 or higher, as null safety is fully supported in these versions.
3. Run the following command to upgrade your project's dependencies and migrate to null safety:

   ```bash
   flutter pub upgrade --null-safety
   ```
4. After upgrading, you should be able to add the "video_player" and "showcaseview" dependencies to your `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     video_player: ^2.2.14 # Add the latest version
     showcaseview: ^0.1.5  # Add the latest version
   ```
5. Run `flutter pub get` to fetch the new dependencies and ensure your project is set up with null safety.

Remember to update the version numbers to the latest versions available at the time of adding the dependencies.